# Why can't I access sources.list.d?

Tags: linux-mint

And what are all the questions marks for?  scroll down for strange output.

```
$ ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/.': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/..': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? additional-repositories.list
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? official-package-repositories.list
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? opera-stable.list
```

Comment: Corrupt filesystem? Try rebooting and running an fsck

Comment: You're missing a permission bit (either read or execute, I forget) on the directory itself. Edit - but the proper solution is that you need to run that command as root.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Cannot access a directory with permissions drw-rw-r--](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/174426)